# Late 1950's early 1960's Cold War Futuristic TV drama

Tags: story-identification, tv

I was pretty young when I saw this sometime between 1959-1963.  Perhaps it was on one of those anthologies like CBS Playhouse.  I believe it takes place in part of the U.S. that has been occupied by a foreign power.  The protagonist is a prisoner in a concentration camp during winter.  They are melting snow for the water to make concrete or mortar for the walls they (similar to the Berlin Wall) have been ordered to build.  The one scene I remember is that he is having a philosophical discussion with the commandant about the best society for humans and he expects to be free sometime in the future. The commandant tells him he sees a "future of camps like this one, and man is to serve his life working for the State" or something like that.

Comment: Were the bad guys supposed to be Korean and/or Chinese? Was there a chess game involved?

Comment: I am fairly certain they were supposed to be eastern European.

Comment: Oh, well. I was thinking of the adaption of Vonnegut's [*All the Kings Horses*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_King%27s_Horses_%28story%29)

Comment: My impression was that the main character was portrayed by one of the actors that had always had a guest starring role on some of the then current tv shows (Mission: Impossible, Bonanza, Combat!, etc..  Never an A lister always a B.  I have spent quite a bit of time on IMDB/google trying to find pictures of guest stars from that era figuring if I find him, I can find the show